# Unity - When running url imported from aws s3 on the video player, I get errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When running url imported from awss3 on the video player, I get errors like "AVFoundationVideoMedia error while reading" and "VideoPlayer cannot play url".

I'm using the following code to get url of the video in aws s3.

```
public async Task<string> GetObjectUrl(AWSCredentials credentials, string keyName)
{
    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, RegionEndpoint.APNortheast2))
    {
        try
        {
            GetPreSignedUrlRequest request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
            {
                BucketName = BUCKET_NAME,
                Key = keyName,
                Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10)
            };

            return client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
        }
        catch (AmazonS3Exception e)
        {
            // If the bucket or the object do not exist
            Debug.Log($"Error: '{e.Message}'");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code receives url in the form of

```
https://~?X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Security-Token=~
```

But if I give this url to url in video player,

> AVFoundationVideoMedia error while reading 'url' Context: AVFoundationVideoMedia::OpenForRead found no video tracks
> Error details:

error and

> VideoPlayer cannot play url: 'url' Cannot read file.

Error appears.

I originally used the version of unity `2021.3.8f1`, which I had no problem with when using it, but this happened after upgrading the version to unity `2022.3.11f1`.

I need to stream a video and I do **not** want to download and play the video through `UnityWebRequest`.

Someone says that from the 2022 version onwards, there must be a clear URL ending in .mp4, but how do you proceed with executing a video player through a URL when there is an https and an authentication token query in one URL?

Comment: well an auth token can be sent as headers but, i dont see a server name in there

Comment: @BugFinder I think OPs issue is not about how to make the request to amazon API in the first place but rather, OP already has a working request, returning the expected correct URL (at least from the description it sounds like this perfectly worked in the past) - however, starting from Unity 2022 the VideoPlayer seems to not support this URL format anymore

Comment: maybe but "https://~?X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-Security-Token=~" is not a url.. its a bunch of parameters without a url :P unless  ~ has been substituted for our sanity

Comment: @BugFinder The URL returned through the above code worked fine on the Unity 2021.3.8f1 version of the video player. It also works perfectly even if I receive the URL directly and use it in an Internet browser. But this url doesn't work with unity 2022.3.11f1 version of video player. It's a problem I'm currently facing. 

 I receive the url of the video file stored in aws s3 using aws credential, so I have no choice but to receive the url encrypted with https. This means that the URL I'm trying to use cannot end up in the .mp4 format.

Comment: @BugFinder https://forum.unity.com/threads/video-player-not-playing-from-url-in-newer-unity-versions.1396417/ Looking at this link, it seems that the problem occurs when it doesn't end with this mp4, but I thought there might be a problem with the encoding part, so I linked aws together and asked questions. I apologize if this has caused you any confusion.